# Get unique rows of each customer_id in from large parquet files for AWS Athena table using python or pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, parquet

How to clean up parquet files in s3 that has 250 million rows in total, partitioned by as_of_date column as shown below in df?.

Note: For depicting my input and wanted output, I am using pandas python just here. But Actually I am ok using other than pandas in python because this is huge data (I am ok with pyspark also)

please run the below code for df and df_output

```
dict_1 = {'customer_id': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
          'is_active': ['y','y','n','n','n','y','y','n'],
          'city':['NYC','NYC','NYC','NYC','SFO','SFO','SFO','SFO'],
         'married_status':['Single','Single','Single','Single','Single','Single','Single','Single'],
         'as_of_date':['01/01/2023', '01/02/2023','01/03/2023','01/04/2023','01/01/2023','01/02/2023','01/03/2023','01/04/2023']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_1, columns = ['customer_id','is_active','city','married_status','as_of_date'])
df1
```

```
dict_output = {'customer_id': [1,1,2,2,2],
          'is_active': ['y','n','n','y','n'],
          'city':['NYC','NYC','SFO','SFO','SFO'],
         'married_status':['Single','Single','Single','Single','Single'],
         'as_of_date':['01/01/2023', '01/03/2023','01/01/2023','01/02/2023','01/04/2023']}
df_output = pd.DataFrame(dict_output, columns = ['customer_id','is_active','city','married_status','as_of_date'])
df_output
```

Here, the output parquet files should contain only distinct rows of each customer (like group by) excluding as_of_date and that row respective as_of_date value.

I have like 300,000 unique customer_id.

Please let me know if you didnt get the question.

Thank you!

Comment: You did not actually state your question. “Show/tell me how to solve this coding problem” [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). We expect you to [make an honest attempt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.